# SVG not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg

I am a newbie with SVG, this is my SVG code:

```
<div style="width:650px;">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
<rect width="640" height="200" style="fill:#ddd;"></rect>
<polyline points="0 200,20 200, 40 200, 60 200, 80 200, 100 200, 120 200, 140 200, 160 200, 180 200, 200 200, 220 200, 240 200, 260 200, 280 200, 300 200, 320 200, 340 200, 360 200, 380 200, 400 200, 420 200, 440 200, 460 101, 480 200, 500 200, 520 2, 540 35, 560 167, 580 167, 600 200, 620 167, 640 200, 640 200" style="fill:blue; stroke:grey; stroke-width:3; opacity:0.4;"></polyline>
</svg></div>
```

i am trying to make analytics table for my site, and it shuold look like img on this link http://1zh.us/examples/svg.jpg
this is link of code http://1zh.us/examples/svg.html
it is working in IE and chrome but not in mozilla firefox.
What i am doing wrong???

Comment: Please put some effort into your question and explain what your problem is. We should not need to test it ourselves just to know what the question is about.

Comment: Alvaro i had make some edit, but i dont know what exact problem is. it just dont show up in firefox in right size and dont have polyline.

Comment: The exact problem is that the `<polyline>` does not render in Firefox; only the `<rect>` shows up ;-)

Comment: is there anything that i can do to fix it, or it is a bug with firefox?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `points` of a `polyline` the commas go between the `x` and `y` values, spaces separate the points.

```
<polyline points="0,200 20,200 40,200 60,200 80,200 100,200 120,200 140,200 160,200
 180,200 200,200 220,200 240,200 260,200 280,200 300,200 320,200 340,200 360,200 380,200 
 400,200 420,200 440,200 460,101 480,200 500,200 520,2 540,35 560,167 580,167 600,200 
 620,167 640,200 640,200"
 style="fill:blue; stroke:grey; stroke-width:3; opacity:0.4;">
</polyline>
```

You also need to make your SVG element large enough to contain your `polyline`:

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="200" width="640">
```